# Is there a way to sharescreen using WebRTC on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, video-streaming, webrtc

I've built webRTC for Android, and I'd like to use it to share screen. 
Is there a way to send either do it out-of-the-box or push a stream of my own frames as a video source.

Answer (score 0):

I've added an example below that shows how to configure a screen share as a video source and add it as a track on a stream.

Get the VideoCapturer

```
@TargetApi(21)
private VideoCapturer createScreenCapturer() {
    if (mMediaProjectionPermissionResultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        report("User didn't give permission to capture the screen.");
        return null;
    }
    return new ScreenCapturerAndroid(
            mMediaProjectionPermissionResultData, new MediaProjection.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            report("User revoked permission to capture the screen.");
        }
    });
}
```

Initialize the capturer and add the tracks to the local media stream

```
private void initScreenCapturStream() {
    mLocalMediaStream = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
    MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxHeight", Integer.toString(mPeerConnParams.videoHeight)));
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxWidth", Integer.toString(mPeerConnParams.videoWidth)));
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxFrameRate", Integer.toString(mPeerConnParams.videoFps)));
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("minFrameRate", Integer.toString(mPeerConnParams.videoFps)));

    mVideoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer);
    videoCapturer.startCapture(mPeerConnParams.videoWidth, mPeerConnParams.videoHeight, mPeerConnParams.videoFps);
    VideoTrack localVideoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, mVideoSource);
    localVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
    mLocalMediaStream.addTrack(factory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv0", mVideoSource));
    AudioSource audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
    mLocalMediaStream.addTrack(factory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource));

    mListener.onStatusChanged("STREAMING");
}
```

For more information this might be a good place to start.  Its a Android project that connects to a ProjectRTC signalling server and shares the screen as video.  I found it very helpful!

https://github.com/Jeffiano/ScreenShareRTC